# How can I create a launcher and Block java status bar and settings app?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a launcher, where access to the device settings is blocked, but I don't have much idea how to do it.
I'm investigating what can be done with

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName adminComponent = new ComponentName(this, testclass.class);

        dpm.setSettingsProviderDisabled(adminComponent, true);
```

but the setSettingsProviderDisabled appears as rename, correctly import the DevicePolicyManager class and the test class extends from DeviceAdminReceiver,
Is there any other way to do it or what do you recommend?

Comment: You should be looking into kiosk mode.

Comment: Apart from that way, is there another way?